# number of mappers created in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

To calculate the number of mappers the job tracker will create is simple to understand. It will basically be the size of the hdfs file divided by the split size. So if the size of hdfs file is 640MB and the split is 64MB then job tracker will be creating 10 mappers. But sometimes the number of mappers created is more than what you would expect. I look at the prints on the screen when the job finishes to understand the number of mappers created.

My question is the following: is it possible understand why more mappers were created, maybe by looking at the different logs?

**Note**: I have a map reduce job and the same job when executed at different times report differnet mappers. Although the extra mappers created is not huge.

Comment: What's your input format, what's the file compression if any, and are the number of files constant between each run where you're observing fluctuating mapper counts (basically you should not see variable number of mappers if files remain the same between job invocations)

Comment: Input format is text, no compression. There is just one file which is huge. I thought that the number of minimum mappers created is equal to file size / input split size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I figured out after reading the logs generated by the job tracker is the extra mappers are created when the already assigned mappers are taking a long time to finish, which are nothing but the stragglers.

Hadoop when assigns such a task, it does it as following:
                               attempt_200707121733_0002_m_000005_1

This means that the job tracker is now trying to assign 1st task attempt for job 2 on the 5th map task. The task attempts start from 0.

Comment: This is called speculative execution. More details [here](http://adhoop.wordpress.com/2012/02/24/speculative-execution-in-hadoop/) and [here](https://www.inkling.com/read/hadoop-definitive-guide-tom-white-3rd/chapter-6/task-execution).